# save a file to /usr using Mac's Save As dialogue

Tags: macos

I'm using OSX currently, but I usually use Windows. One thing that's really frustrating for me is that I can't figure out how to save a file to a very specific location (/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.1/conf/xyz.conf)

When I click Save As in Sublime Text I get a save dialogue with only a few very limited choices (I assume this is a generic dialogue to Mac OS and not specific to Sublime). I learned to click the downward arrow next to the file name which expands the dialogue somewhat, but I still don't see how I can save the file in /usr since that folder is seemingly missing. Any idea?

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Related is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39006/navigate-folder-structure-in-open-save-file-dialog-with-keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does indeed appear to be a regular save dialog, so once you've expanded it (the down-arrow next to 'Where' so you get a mini-finder view), the key combo <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> should toggle invisibles.

(The same combo works in Finder proper, also)

Comment: This feature has worked in Open and Save dialogs for a long time, but was only added to the Finder in macOS Sierra (10.12).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to just have invisibles always visible?

Answer (score 4):

In standard Open and Save dialogs (and in the Finder), you can press Command-Shift-G and then enter the unix-style path to the folder you want (e.g. "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.1/conf"). Note that tab-completion works here, so you don't actually have to type everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the list of options one option should be your computer. Once you select your computer you should be able to save the file anywhere. You may not have permission to save in some directories though. Shown below is a connection to my computer.

[image]

Comment: My problem is that after clicking on Macintosh HD there is no /usr. There is a Users folder, but I believe that is a different thing. So my question is how I can expose the /usr folder since I bet it is hidden by default

Comment: Some folders are hidden by the system, Library and usr are to such directory. Only was I've found to save to user is to open a Finder Window. Then from command line type: 'defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'. This tells computer to make invisible files visible.  Now go back to Finder window and click on you hard drive.  You should see usr but it won't be highlighted. Now click on usr and drag it to the sidebar under the Favorites label. Now usr will be accessible everytime you tried to save a file.

Comment: The /Usr folder is hidden by default and can't, generally, be browsed to. Not being familiar with Sublime Text I don't know if there is an option to allow it to show invisibles, which you would need to do in a GUI application. If you did this in one of the command line editors (VI, etc.) that limitation would not exist.